# Fitting graph and draw lines by selecting ranges in horizontal axis

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot a graph and fitting it using a linear line.

```
f1(x)=a1+b1*x
fit [0:80] f1(x) 'diff-xy-bcmLyo25perS.dat' via a1,b1

f2(x)=a2+b2*x
fit [100:220] f2(x) 'diff-xy-bcmLyo25perS.dat' via a2,b2
```

And I tried to plot both the plots into the same graph using command:

```
f(x) = x < 60 ? f1(x) : f2(x)

plot    'diff-xy-bcmLyo25perS.dat' using 1:2 with lines linestyle 1 title "{/Symbol b}BCMal-C_{12}C_{8}", f(x) lw 3.0 lc rgb 'black'
```

[image: here]

I get a plot as above.

In that plot one could see that there are two lines intersecting at 80 (horizontal scale) and it makes shape like 'v'.

I wish to eliminate that 'v' shape intersection and I would like to get two separate lines, one from **0 to 80** and the other one from **100 to 220**.

How I could get this?

Appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could exploit that gnuplot doesn't plot `infinity` and `NaN` values (as `1.0/0`)

Using

```
plot_if_in_range(y,x,lower,upper) = (x>=lower && x<=upper)?(y):(1.0/0)
```

You could easily plot any function in given domain:

```
plot  plot_if_in_range(exp(x)  , x, -5, 2), \
      plot_if_in_range(sin(x)+x, x, -2, 5)
```

Answer (score 3):

With gnuplot 5.0 you can specify different range for different functions:

```
set style data lines
plot 'diff-xy-bcmLyo25perS.dat' using 1:2 ls 1, \
    [0:80] f1(x) lw 3.0 lc rgb 'black',\
    [100:220] f2(x) lw 3.0 lc rgb 'black'
```

Note, that this works only, because you first plot the data file. Plotting only

```
plot [0:80] f1(x), [100:220] f2(x)
```

wouldn't work, since the first range settings are equivalent to a global `set xrange [0:80]` (it has always been), so that the second function wouldn't be visible at all.

However, in your case it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I installed GNUPLOT 5.0 and tried to run the existing script for plotting,  but I get an error syaing "unknown or ambiguous terminal type; type just 'set terminal' for a list". Why the PNG is not working? I configured as (./configure --with-cairo). Is there any tweaks need to be done?

Comment: However, I used postscript terminal and it works fine.

Comment: I don't know, maybe you don't have all library headers, see the screen output after running `./configure`, or the `config.log` for details.

Comment: Dear #Christoph, I defined the line style as (set style line 1 lt 1 lc rgb "red"  lw 2.0). When I use this in a plot command as (plot 'diff-xy-bcmLyo25perS.dat' using 1:2 ls 1), I get line type as "+". I have tried to get simple solid line but I could not. Could you explain why I am getting "+" and how to get simple line? Thank you

Comment: Specify a plotting style with `plot ... with lines`

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
Sorry, this is basically the same idea as Sergei Izmailov's answer which I missed.

**Answer:**

Use the special file `"+"`, which provides x values for your plot that you can then sample using a function of your choice, including one that ignores input if it's outside of range. Then you can use your `f1(x)` and `f2(x)` directly:

```
plot "+" using ($1):(0 < $1 && $1 < 80 ? f1($1) : 1/0), \
"+" using ($1):(100 < $1 && $1 < 220 ? f2($1) : 1/0)
```